# Jupyter notebook on Docker not working behind proxy

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently running anaconda docker using Docker tool box on a windows 7 machine.
The jupyter notebook perfectly works fine at home when there is no proxy used.
But in office when i try to open the notebook behind the proxy it does not open up.

Please guide me.